# How do I apply a ton of button classes only to certain buttons?

Tags: button

So I want to add this: http://codepen.io/tstoik/pen/EjMzRZ to my site and I was successful but, I only want it to work on buttons with id: cool or class: cool (shown below). Either one would be just fine.

```
<a href="#" class="btn red" id="cool" title="Red">Red</a>
<a href="#" class="btn red cool" title="Red">Red</a>
```

The CSS is in the codepen and is too big to copy here.
So, is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just edit the js to only target the `cool` class.

All I did was add cool to the green button, and then change the js from:

```
$('.btn').prepend('<div class="hover"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>');
```

To:

```
$('.btn.cool').prepend('<div class="hover"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>');
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/2bpfvjzu/

Comment: For some reason, when I try to apply this to my submit button using the code below: 
`<input type="button" class="btn green cool" value="Submit" onclick="submit();"/>`  The cool effect when you hover does not seem to work...  What do I need to change in the js to fix this?  THANKS :D

Comment: Putting a `div` inside of `input` is not valid html, the code will require some major surgery to work with `input` elements.